# EclipseLink add vs. update performance

Tags: java, sql-server, database, eclipselink

Can anybody give me an intuition for the following situation?

We are modifying our Microsoft SQL server with EclipseLink. Our application contains an import functionality, so that from these imports a lot of insertions into a table (say table A) are generated. On the other hand, when we delete one of these entries of the table, we do not actually delete it but set a "deleted" flag to true. Among different tables (say tables X,Y,Z), there are relations, so that if we delete an element from X, we also delete some elements of A. Important is that we insert and delete every element separately for now. Given a lot of imports and and a lot of such bulk updates (our deletions), our table A grows a lot, so that currently it is of size 500'000.

Using the EclipseLink PerformanceProfiler, I found out that we get a slow-down in update times, but no visible slow-down for the insertion time. Since we have an index on the composite primary key of table A, I expect that insertion needs O(1) time for index insertion (assuming that the index is similar to a HashMap) and something like O(1) to insert into the table. For the update, I get O(1) for retrieval, and O(1) for the write. 
In reality we get an insertion time of 0.6 ms for one element, but an update time of 800ms (!). Does anybody have an explanation for this? Also, if anybody knows good measures to improve this situation, I am happy to hear those as well.

So far I am only aware of bulk updating those elements together that meet a certain condition such as: update all elements of table A that are related to element x of table X. But since we have a lot more hierarchy over multiple tables, I am not sure how much I get from this.

Comment: Hello Ben, the 800ms seconds, are they measured on the SQL server or or the java side? A insert is cheaper for JPA, since it has not to revalidate/flush the whole object tree. When writing a update back to the database, JPA has to check the whole in-memory objecttree which (possibly related) objects have been modified too.

Comment: The 800ms were measured on the Java side using the PerformanceProfiler of eclipselink. Can I somehow tell JPA that there are no other related changes? In case of changing the delete flag, I am sure that nothing else has changed.

Comment: more information is needed - are you talking about actual SQL update/insert times or the time taken to process what you have done in an EntityManager via flush/commit?  batch writing helps with performance as it means less statements back and forth - how much performance you will get depends entirely on your application model and usage, and of course depends on what is causing the majority of your slowdown.

Comment: From what I can see, this is sql execution time excluding the entitymanager execution preparation.